# Removing rows from a pandas dataframe if a column contains a particular word alone

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a pandas dataframe from which i have to remove rows if it contains a particular word alone. For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['Team 1', 'Team 1 abc', 'Team 2',
                            'Team 3', 'Team 2', 'Team 3'],
                   'Subject': ['Math', 'Science', 'Science', 
                               'Math', 'Science', 'Math'],
                   'points': [10, 8, 10, 6, 6, 5]})
```

I tried to remove rows which contain `Team 1` alone. For that I tried,

```
df = df[df["team"].str.contains("Team 1") == False]
```

and I got the dataframe like

[image]

The dataframe I needed as follows with row number also should be in order

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `!=` instead of `.str.contains`:

```
df = df[df["team"] != "Team 1"]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         team  Subject  points
1  Team 1 abc  Science       8
2      Team 2  Science      10
3      Team 3     Math       6
4      Team 2  Science       6
5      Team 3     Math       5
```

Comment: The row number is not in order in this case :( How can I make the row number in order.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Try `df = df[df["team"] != "Team 1"].reset_index(drop=True)`